# Enthought Canopy 64bit on OSX: import pyglet.gl failure

Tags: enthought, pyglet, canopy

### Retaining question for posterity; see workaround in edit

The Pyglet package comes installed at base and isn't removable. Using the current fully updated version 1.1.4 of Pyglet, I get repeatable errors related to importing the item `pyglet.gl.gl_info`; for instance, upon attempting to create a `pyglet.window.Window()`, upon trying to `import pyglet.gl`, or upon attempting to import pygarrayimage via `from pygarrayimage.arrayimage import ArrayInterfaceImage`.

In all such cases the relevant traceback ends with the uninformative message:

```
/Users/[username]/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/System/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyglet/image/__init__.py in <module>()
    142 
    143 from pyglet import gl
--> 144 from pyglet.gl import *
    145 from pyglet.gl import gl_info
    146 from pyglet import graphics

/Users/[username]/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/System/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyglet/gl/__init__.py in <module>()
    102 from pyglet.gl.glext_arb import *
    103 from pyglet.gl.glext_missing import *
--> 104 from pyglet.gl import gl_info
    105 
    106 import sys as _sys

ImportError: cannot import name gl_info
```

I am using OSX 10.6.8 on an Intel processor, with Canopy 64-bit, and these are 100% repeatable.

Given the traceback one might assume `gl_info` mistakenly isn't included, but this isn't the case. `dir(pyglet.gl.gl_info)` can successfully be run.

### **Edit: Solved this problem.**

Pyglet 1.1.4 does not support 64-bit on OSX, so until Enthought packages a newer release of Pyglet in Canopy, here is a workaround for 64-bit OSX users.

1. Acquire source for any release of Pyglet 1.2alpha1 or beyond.
2. Extract source to your directory of choice.
3. Append this directory to the **beginning** of your PYTHONPATH environment variable, in **both** `~/.bash_profile` (for terminal shells) and `/etc/launchd.conf` (for GUI processes) with a line similar to: `export PYTHONPATH=/Users/[username]/src/pyglet-1.2alpha1:$PYTHONPATH`
4. Run this bash command in an unrelated directory and confirm the path printed leads to your 1.2alpha1 source directory: `$ python -c "import pyglet; print pyglet.__path__[0]"`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't wish to modify your bash_profile, you can simply do the following:

1. Extract latest Pyglet source to your directory of choice and cd to that directory (it should contain a setup.py file).
2. Use Canopy's Python to install Pyglet by doing the following (on Mac 64 bit):
   `~/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/python setup.py install`

The location of Canopy's Python for different platforms is listed here:
https://support.enthought.com/entries/23646538-Make-Canopy-s-Python-be-your-default-Python-i-e-on-the-PATH-